# Formula to check if working out of hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to find out if someone was not working during 'out of hours'.

- If Monday to Friday, not between the hours of, 8am to 9pm, then the answer would be "Yes"
- If it's a Saturday, not between the hours of, 8am to 5pm, the answer
  would be "Yes"
- If it's a Sunday, not between the hours of, 9am to 5pm, the answer
  would be "Yes".

Otherwise the answer would be "No".

There are 4 columns: 1. Person's Name (A) 2. Date (B) 3. Time (C) 4. Out of Hours (D)

I've copied in the formula below which is working correctly for Monday to Friday, but I'm struggling with the second part of the weekend one.

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(B2)=1,WEEKDAY(B2)=7),"Yes",IF(AND(C2>=8/24,C2<21/24),"No","Yes"))
```

If anyone could advise on how to change the formula to work with 'out of hours' for Saturday and Sunday?

It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(B2)=7,IF(OR(C2<TIMEVALUE("8:00"),C2>TIMEVALUE("17:00"))=TRUE,"Yes","No"),IF(WEEKDAY(B2)=1,IF(OR(C2<TIMEVALUE("9:00"),C2>TIMEVALUE("17:00"))=TRUE,"Yes","No"),IF(WEEKDAY(B2)<>1,IF(OR(C2<TIMEVALUE("8:00"),C2>TIMEVALUE("21:00"))=TRUE,"Yes","No"),"No")))
```

You will have to use nested ifs. Hope above formula will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `WEEKDAY(B2)` will be from 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday), you can use `CHOOSE` to select the Start/End time for your "In-Hours" period:

Start: `=Choose(Weekday(B2),9,8,8,8,8,8,8)`

End: `=Choose(Weekday(B2),17,21,21,21,21,21,17)`

So, if `HOUR(C2)` is `>=` *Start*, and `HOUR(C2)` is `<` *End* then you are "In-Hours" ("No"), otherwise you are "Out of Hours" ("Yes")

```
=IF(AND(HOUR(C2)>=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(B2),9,8,8,8,8,8,8), HOUR(C2)<CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(B2),17,21,21,21,21,21,17)),"No","Yes")
```

Of course, I would *recommend* replacing the `CHOOSE`s with a pair of `VLOOKUP`s, and having a hidden sheet where you list the Weekday and the Start/End-of-Hours hours.  (Much easier to update if **The Boss** decides to change the hours!)

Comment: Chronocidal, I agree, from past experience when creating complex worksheets and formulas that rely on data like times and set values, occasionally these change and then every formula would have to be updated manually. Using values in a hidden sheet means at any time they can be instantly changed without amending the whole workbook. Also excellent for testing formulas in different situations,

Comment: Of course, if they change then you won't usually want to back-date the changes.  You should probably put your Weekdays across the top (columns B-H), and place each time change in a new row with the start date so that you can use a Range Lookup: `VLOOKUP($B2, 'Work Hours Control'!$A:$H,1+Weekday($B2), TRUE)`

Comment: Excellent point, I tend to work with current/live data and not so much past data, something to think about.